# How to assign an object's property to another one of it's properties in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in reactjs so please bear with me. I am using `state` and `setState` in my class component, thing is I want to reference `value1`,`value2` and `value3` properties in `setState` inside the `answerIsFalse` arrow function as seen in the code below to `proposedAnswer` and `check` properties in the same `setState` instead of `currentState` because I want to re-assign their values and pass them to `state`. I tried using `this`, binding it, and `setState.value1` for example but nothing worked.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    const value1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const value2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const value3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const proposedAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + value1 + value2 + value3;
    const numQuestions = 0;
    const numCorrect = 0;
    const check = proposedAnswer === value1 + value2 + value3;
    this.state = {
    value1: value1,
    value2: value2,
    value3: value3,
    proposedAnswer: proposedAnswer,
    numQuestions: numQuestions,
    numCorrect: numCorrect,
    check: check
    };
    
    
  }
  
  
  
  answerIsTrue = () => {
    console.log(this);
    this.setState ((currentState) => ({
        numCorrect: currentState.check ? currentState.numCorrect + 1 : currentState.numCorrect,
        numQuestions: currentState.numQuestions + 1,
        value1: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        value2: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        value3: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        proposedAnswer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + currentState.value1 + currentState.value2 + currentState.value3,
        check: currentState.proposedAnswer === currentState.value1 + currentState.value2 + currentState.value3
        
        
     }))
 }
  
  answerIsFalse = () => {
    console.log(this);
    this.setState ((currentState) => ({
        numCorrect: currentState.check ? currentState.numCorrect : currentState.numCorrect + 1,
        numQuestions: currentState.numQuestions + 1,
        value1: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        value2: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        value3: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        proposedAnswer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + currentState.value1 + currentState.value2 + currentState.value3,
        check: currentState.proposedAnswer === currentState.value1 + currentState.value2 + currentState.value3
        
        
     }))
 }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="game">
          <h2>Mental Math</h2>
          <div className="equation">
            <p className="text">{`${this.state.value1} + ${this.state.value2} + ${this.state.value3} = ${this.state.proposedAnswer}`}</p>
          </div>
          <button 
          onClick = {() => this.answerIsTrue()}
          >
          True
          </button>
          <button onClick = {() => this.answerIsFalse()}>
          False
          </button>
          <p className="text">
            Your Score: {this.state.numCorrect}/{this.state.numQuestions}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full component code so its easier for people to help you.

Comment: At least I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what exactly you're trying to do. Do you mean that you want to use the new values of `value1`, `value2` and `value3` for the `proposedAnswer` and `check`? In that case you could simply take their new values to a variable before the `setState` call and reference those variables instead of `currentState.value1` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you may be having a misconception of how `state` and `setState` works.

The `state` object is supposed to be immutable, so to "modify" it you need to re-write it every time. For example:

```js
this.state = { age: 25, name: 'John' }
```

To change the `age` attribute, you need to use `setState()` and pass it a new `state` object.

```js
this.setState({ ...this.state, age: 30}) // {age: 30, name: 'John'}
```

In this case `this.state` is giving me access to the current state and all its attributes as they were defined before. To make it more clear:

```js
let newState = { ...this.state, age: 30} 
this.setState(newState) // {age: 30, name: 'John'}
```

Keep in mind you never have to overwrite `this.state` but always create a new object and pass it to `this.setState()` as an argument to be able to modify a component state.

Check out the [React's state docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) and the [spread operator docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Also, it seems that your `answerIsFalse` and `answerIsTrue` methods share a lot of code and you may want to refactor them.
Some of that code can be reused if you put it in its own method, for example:

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
```

You could do something like this:

```js
const getRandomValue = (factor) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * factor)
}
```

And then use it like this: `this.getRandomValue(100)` or `this.getRandomValue(3)` when you need them.

Also, the names are a bit confusing (to me, at least) as may imply that the methods return boolean values but in reality are changing the component's state. I would rename them to something like `setAnswerToFalse` or something like that.